# How to check if files have been modified?

Tags: python, logging

Okay, so I'm looking for an easy way to check if the contents of files in a folder have changed. And if one did change, it updates the version of that file.
I'm guessing this is what is called logging? I'm am completely new to this, so is a bit hard to explain the concept of what I'm looking for. I'll give an example:

Let's I have a reference folder that contains my original data.
Then for every time I run my code it inspects the contents of the files in said reference folder.
If the contents are the same, then it the code continues to run normally.
But if the contents of the files have changed, it updates the version of that file (for example: from '1.0.0' to '1.0.1') and keeps a copy of the changes.

Is there a way to do this in python or a module that helps me accomplish this? Or where can I start looking into this?

Comment: What OS? On Linux you can use inotify to trigger your application when a file is modified.

Comment: Logging typically describes *your* program writing output to indicate the status or progress of your program. What you want is to *monitor* some part of the file system. Doing this efficiently requires OS-specific support, but you might want to start with the [`watchdog` package](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/).

Comment: @jordanm Yes, my OS is Linux.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the clarification! I'll look into it.

Comment: You can always resort to checksumming the files and compare the results with those from the last run. You can run commands like md5sum or sha1sum for that.

Comment: Just a thought... aren't you just in need of using (or calling) a version control tool over your files?

Comment: @progmatico If that is what I think it is then, yes. Or at least, it is a major operation of what I want to do.

Comment: Unless your project is writing another version control tool, I would select one of the existing ones and use it. May I ask if you ever used such thing (most people here have, but not everyone of course)?

Comment: @progmatico Never have.

Comment: Ok, Only difference for what you ask is that modern version control tools version use changesets, or "project images" instead of versioning at file level. This is actually much better for the end user because for a given overall state (project version) you do not have to care about which version is each file.

Comment: I am supposing your "data" are text files. Besides, it would be good for you to use version control for your own code if you write it.

Comment: Take a look at [git](https://git-scm.com/), [hg](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/) and [fossil](https://fossil-scm.org/home/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) to select one that you like.